# SetSysTrayVisible bug Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, system-tray

There is a random bug as mentioned below which says something wrong while setting the `SystemTray` visibility. I have set the `SystemTray` visibility to false in xaml. It randomly crashes the app sometimes and not always. The exception thrown is  `System.ArgumentException` `Value does not fall within the expected range.`

The stacktrace is as below

```
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.NativeSystemTrayMethods.SetSysTrayVisible(IntPtr pSysTray, Boolean fVisible)    
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.NativeSystemTrayInteropWrapper.SetSystemTrayVisible(Boolean isVisible)
Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.set_SystemTrayIsVisible(Boolean value)
Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage..ctor()
```

What can be the probable reason for it? Any workarounds? Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: check with any other page or creating a new page whether the issue happening or not.

Comment: No, its random. Check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/62ffbd7f-d7fa-4b68-ba65-cd4e851f0b6c/is-this-stack-trace-a-bug-in-wp8-systemtrayisvisibletrue?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: check again. link wasn't correct.

Comment: Is the page completely loaded when you are receiving this error? Can you move the Visibility into the Page.Loaded event, so that it only fires when the page is fully loaded?

Comment: As per Paul's comments in the linked forum thread: Can you share the XAML of the page where this happens? A whole app that can reproduce this would also be useful if you're doing anything other than the default with the PhoneApplicationFrame. What devices is this happening on? Anything else you can say about when/where this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution in any way.

We are seeing the same error mostly (90%) on WP8.0 devices and there is a very very small percentage of WP8.1 devices. Other error reports do not contain version of the OS for some reason.

Here is what we found out with advanced technical support from Microsoft.

> This is a known problem that **was fixed for WP8.1**.
>
> I looked at the SetSystemTrayVisible bug that stack trace suggests and confirmed should be fixed in WP8.1.
>
> I’m not sure why you’re seeing some instances on 8.10.14234, but there may be a second, rarer, issue in that area
>
> Unfortunately, there isn’t anything you can do in your code to prevent this on WP8.0. The problem occurs in the root page initialization where it’s setting the default state of the system tray. There’s an incorrect guard check in native interop, so if a handle gets initialized to a bad value the exception is raised. The guard was fixed for WP8.1
>
> You should be able to detect the error ... expect it to trigger the Application_UnhandledException handler from which you can display a message box.

So the best way to handle that exception is to just catch it (detect) and then suggest user to upgrade the OS to WP8.1.
I am not sure how feasible is that cause we were unable to reproduce this error on our devices or emulators.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the .dll's loaded into **Visual Studio**!
also make sure you wrote the string all the way to the top of the `page.xaml.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
```

I have already done that and it works like a charm for me!

```
//Fullscreen mode.
SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
```

***Regards! //Bachir Bouchemla***